# Merge iOS DBs for SMS Messages & Photos from 2 iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, jailbreak, sms

Merge iOS DBs for SMS Messages & Photos from 2 iPhones?

- i7 iOS 11.2.6 - Unused phone

---

- i5 iOS 10.3.3 - (Used until 2017)
- i6 iOS 10.2 - (Used most of 2018)

All are Jailbroken.

- Would like to Merge the DBs from i5 and i6 into one of them and eventually transfer to i7.
- How would it be possible to Merge the DBs of i5 & i6?

If not directly via iMazing, any suggestions on how to Merge the DB files as some people are well aware of structure (since iMazing & similar tools can read / access the files).

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?